# Why would i install bower with NPM?

Tags: angularjs, npm, bower

I'm failing to understand something,

I've started learning AngularJS, and there is a option to install it trough bower.
Then i went and read what is this bower thingy, and **[it](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/meet-bower-a-package-manager-for-the-web--net-27774)** said that this is a package manager.
But the installation of bower (in the tutorial at least) is trough NPM, which is node's package manager.

So... Why would a package manager that is installed with node will be used to install AngularJS? unless i want to use both of them - what's the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm is much more well suited for server side javascript package management. Bower is written specifically to serve the brower's javascript package management needs. For example, npm allows for nested js and nested versions, bower makes the entire dependency tree into flat siblings. That said bower is powered by nodejs, so it makes sense that npm would be the method for getting access to bower. The idea is that you use both.